# Why can't find "com.lowagie.text.rtf"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I meet an error "cannot resolve symbol rtf", but I have already added these:
iText-5.0.6.jar
iText-rtf-2.1.7.jar

I have just moved my multi-module project from eclipse to Idea. It can successfully be deloyed using eclipse, but when I depolyed it on Tomcat at Idea, I met "cannot reslove symbol rtf"

some codes:

```java
import com.lowagie.text.Table;(no error)
import com.lowagie.text.rtf.RtfWriter2;(error)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick way to check about the class and the corresponding jar file. Use the site https://www.findjar.com/index.x and post your class, it will provide you the jar file containing the class.
Check below the link for RtfWriter2 class.

https://www.findjar.com/class/com/lowagie/text/rtf/RtfWriter2.html

Comment: That's a quite awesome site! But I don't know how to search a jar I need accurately. I just input "FacesServlet" and I got many results which are the same name like "[CLASS] javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".

Answer (score 0):

A common issue when switching IDEs are the IDE-specific files like `*.project` or `*.settings` etc. Please get rid of these when trying out a new IDE, especially IntelliJ.

Steps to try:
 - Close the IDE
 - Delete Eclipse-specific files
 - Delete `.idea` folder from project, and the `*.iml` file
 - Open the project again in IntellJ

As always, remember to keep backups before deleting your source code.

Comment: I tried the steps you provided, but still didn't solve that problem.